# How to make sure a task is executed before starting different services

Tags: upstart

We have the following scenario in upstart:

We have some *task* called **T**, and some *services*, **A** and **B** with the following requirements:

- **T** must run completely isolated from the services **A** and **B**
- Both **A** and **B** can *only* run if task **T** has completed
- **A** and **B** can be started independently

In simple words, **T** is a requirement for both **A** and **B**, but running **T** doesn't necessarily mean that either **A** or **B** should be started.

How can we enforce these requirements in upstart? Adding other "helper" jobs is fine, of course.

---

We tried the following, that doesn't work:

```
# T.conf
task
start on (starting A or starting B)
```

The problem is that if **T** is already running when starting **B**, e.g. because **A** is already about to start, then **B** will just start without waiting for **T** to finish. This violates the first two requirements above.

---

Another option is to explicitly start **T** from the pre-start sections of the services. However, that causes a service to fail to start, instead of waiting, if **T** is already being executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a workaround using this extra helper task (better suggestions are still welcome):

```
start on (starting A or starting B)
task
instance $JOB
script
    until start T; do sleep 1; done
end script
```

This helper job is started just about when either **A** or **B** is about to start, blocking those services. There will be one instance of this task for each service. It will block until **T** is successfully completed.